# JAVA Web Service, not communicating with database

Tags: java, database, web-services, jax-ws

I am trying to get a JAVA web service to communicate with an SQL Server database. After I deploy and test the web-service, I tried some of its methods, but none of the changes are being reflected in the database. For instance:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "readPerson")
    public String readPerson(@WebParam(name = "ID") long id)
    {
        String s = null;

        try {
            String connectionUrl= "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
                        "databaseName=myDatabase;user=sa;password=password;";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

            Statement myStmt  = con.createStatement();

            String query = "SELECT * FROM People WHERE ID=" + id;
            ResultSet rs =  myStmt.executeQuery(query);

            String name = null;
            String surname = null;
            int age = 0;
            long contact = 0;
            String location= null;

            while(rs.next())
            {
                name = rs.getString("Name");            
                surname = rs.getString("Surname");           
                age = rs.getInt("Age");
                contact = rs.getLong("Contact");
                location = rs.getString("Location");
            }

            s =
            "ID: " + Long.toString(id)
            + "\nName: " + name
            + "\nSurname: " + surname
            + "\nAge: " + Integer.toString(age)
            + "\nContact: " + Long.toString(contact)
            + "\nLocation: " + location;


        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return s;

    }
```

When I invoke the web method:

```
readPerson Method invocation

Method parameter(s)
Type    Value
long    1001
Method returned
java.lang.String : "null"
SOAP Request

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <S:Header/>
        <S:Body>
            <ns2:readPerson xmlns:ns2="http://javaservice/">
                <ID>1001</ID>
            </ns2:readPerson>
        </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>

SOAP Response

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <S:Body>
            <ns2:readPersonResponse xmlns:ns2="http://javaservice/"/>
        </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
```

This method is supposed to return a string with the field contents of a record in my "People" table, but when I test it, nothing happens. No errors either. The weird thing is that when I tried this method in a normal application (not a web service), it worked. Any ideas?

EDIT: Glassfish Server output log

```
Jan 26, 2012 1:28:32 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain main
INFO: Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Welcome to Felix
================
INFO: Perform lazy SSL initialization for the listener 'http-listener-2'
INFO: Starting Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o - Thu Jan 26 13:28:36 CET 2012
INFO: Starting Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o - Thu Jan 26 13:28:36 CET 2012
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 155ms listening on port 4848
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 185ms listening on port 8181
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 165ms listening on port 7676
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 229ms listening on port 8080
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 196ms listening on port 3700
INFO: Using com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate as the delegate
INFO: SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.
INFO: Security startup service called
INFO: SEC1143: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
INFO: Realm admin-realm of classtype com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm successfully created.
INFO: Realm file of classtype com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm successfully created.
INFO: Realm certificate of classtype com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm successfully created.
INFO: Security service(s) started successfully....
INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on port 8080
INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on port 8181
INFO: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on port 4848
INFO: Created virtual server server
INFO: Created virtual server __asadmin
INFO: Virtual server server loaded system default web module
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.2 (FCS b10) for context '/JAVAWebClient'
INFO: Loading application JAVAWebClient at /JAVAWebClient
INFO: Loading JAVAWebClient Application done is 8391 ms
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.2 (FCS b10) for context '/WebApplication2'
INFO: Loading application WebApplication2 at /WebApplication2
INFO: Loading WebApplication2 Application done is 1092 ms
INFO: WS00018: Webservice Endpoint deployed
 JavaService  listening at address at http://localhost:8080/JAVAWebService/JavaService
INFO: Loading application JAVAWebService at /JAVAWebService
INFO: Loading JAVAWebService Application done is 747 ms
INFO: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1 (22) startup time : Felix(2951ms) startup services(11001ms) total(13952ms)
INFO: Binding RMI port to *:8686
INFO: JMXStartupService: Started JMXConnector, JMXService URL = service:jmx:rmi://Owner-PC:8686/jndi/rmi://Owner-PC:8686/jmxrmi
INFO: Hibernate Validator bean-validator-3.0-JBoss-4.0.2
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: [Thread[GlassFish Kernel Main Thread,5,main]] started
INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on port 8080
INFO: {felix.fileinstall.poll (ms) = 5000, felix.fileinstall.dir = C:\Users\Owner\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\modules\autostart, felix.fileinstall.debug = 1, felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start = true, felix.fileinstall.tmpdir = C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\fileinstall--5829618408382097172, felix.fileinstall.filter = null}
INFO: {felix.fileinstall.poll (ms) = 5000, felix.fileinstall.dir = C:\Users\Owner\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy\bundles, felix.fileinstall.debug = 1, felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start = true, felix.fileinstall.tmpdir = C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\fileinstall-4786743129504536536, felix.fileinstall.filter = null}
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 81ms listening on port 8080
INFO: Started bundle: file:/C:/Users/Owner/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/modules/autostart/osgi-web-container.jar
INFO: Started bundle: file:/C:/Users/Owner/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/modules/autostart/org.apache.felix.scr.jar
INFO: Perform lazy SSL initialization for the listener 'http-listener-2'
INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on port 8181
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 71ms listening on port 8181
INFO: Updating configuration from org.apache.felix.fileinstall-autodeploy-bundles.cfg
INFO: Installed C:\Users\Owner\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.fileinstall-autodeploy-bundles.cfg
INFO: {felix.fileinstall.poll (ms) = 5000, felix.fileinstall.dir = C:\Users\Owner\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy\bundles, felix.fileinstall.debug = 1, felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start = true, felix.fileinstall.tmpdir = C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\fileinstall--5770451782291429715, felix.fileinstall.filter = null}
INFO: WS00018: Webservice Endpoint deployed
 JavaService  listening at address at http://localhost:8080/JAVAWebService/JavaService
INFO: Loading application JAVAWebService at /JAVAWebService
INFO: JAVAWebService was successfully deployed in 849 milliseconds.
INFO: WSP5018: Loaded WSIT configuration from file: file:/C:/Users/Owner/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JAVAWebService/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/wsit-javaservice.JavaService.xml.
INFO: Metro monitoring rootname successfully set to: amx:pp=/mon/server-mon[server],type=WSEndpoint,name=/JAVAWebService-JavaService-JavaServicePort
INFO: parsing WSDL...

INFO: generating code...

INFO: compiling code...

INFO: Invoking wsimport with http://localhost:8080/JAVAWebService/JavaService?WSDL
INFO: wsimport successful
INFO: parsing WSDL...

INFO: generating code...

INFO: compiling code...

INFO: Invoking wsimport with http://localhost:8080/JAVAWebService/JavaService?WSDL
INFO: wsimport successful
SEVERE: The log message is null.
```

Comment: Despite the code there isn't really anything here for people to work with. If you can't debug the web service in real time to figure out what is happening the best thing you can do is add more logging statements to find out what is happening with your request in the code.

Comment: use Logger.getLogger(JavaService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex.getMessage()); so we can see the response of the exception.

Comment: I've added the Glassfish output panel information. Mind you, invoking the service doesn't cause any errors. No exceptions, nothing. It is as if it works but does nothing..

Comment: Kevin, how can I debug the service? The only option I have is to test it after I deploy.